# Spring autowired annotation constructor parameter

Tags: java, spring

here is my code

class:

```
@Component("testcomp")
public class TestClass {

private String msg;

@Autowired
public TestClass(String msg)
{
    this.msg = msg;
}

}
```

appconfig.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.demo"/>
<bean id="msg" class="java.lang.String" c:_0="Test MSG"/>
```

when i run project i got this error:
"Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.TestClass required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found."

this approach doesn't work for String class. but if i change String type to user defined class it works good.
am i wrong with this or this is not possible to doing so in spring?

Comment: **You can't `@Autowired` a `String` with Spring.** You should consider using properties file and use either Java annoted Spring configuration or XML Spring configuration to link the value of your properties file to the Java property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it doesn't really make sense to inject primitives into a component.

- Either your string is a constant, so make it static final.
- Either your string is a configuration, so put it into your `application.properties` file, and use `@Value("${path.to.your.property.key}")` to inject it.

I haven't try, but I think you can still configure your beans like this :

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

  @Bean(name = "msg")
  public String msg() {
    return "Test MSG";
  }
}

@Component("testcomp")
public class TestClass {

  private String msg;

  @Autowired
  public TestClass(@Qualifier("msg") String msg)
  {
    this.msg = msg;
  }
}
```

But still, there is simplier way to do this.

Comment: actually im new in Spring and i've seen these codes in one of my references. as i understood, if we use annotation for DI, we can't use classes that defined as bean in xml for injection.it is correct?

Comment: I never use xml to configure my beans, so I can't tell.
You can still configure your beans with java anotations, I will edit my answer to show you an exemple.

Comment: i have tried to doing so but Autowired seems doesn't have name attribute. i even tried to use Qualifier with Autowired but these can't be used together for constructor!

Comment: Try to use qualifier only on the constructor param. Sorry for the imprecision of my answer, but I haven't a java environment to try myself.

Comment: Thank you. It worked with java config class even without qualifier annotation. but it didnt work by using xml configuration anymore.